# map design and need to name in mouse hover

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show the map image and when the mouse hovers on the city I need to show pop-up box and candidates info.
(http://edition.cnn.com/ELECTION/2010/results/main.results/#val=S).

In the same procedure I need to put in my application. Is there any right specification or tutorials to get perfect knowledge on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps will allow you to so this and they have many tutorials on how to achieve something like this.

Go here to get started: [Google Maps API Family](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)